# How to link bigcartel subdomain to dugway barebones site

Tags: bigcartel

Hello I am trying to learn how to develop big cartel themes with the dugway api and I am having trouble linking to the subdomain of a companies current products. Per the documentation it says I need to put in the subdomain in the config file.

This is what I have tried so far, in the dugway.json file I have this "store": {
    "subdomain": "kounterfitklothing"
   },
and then restarting the dugway server. Once I do that and refresh the page I still see the dugway barebones page.

I also tried adding options[:store] = 'kounterfitklothing' to the config.ru file and nothing happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that with the latest version, inserting this into the `dugway.json` file will load the store properly (config.ru is no longer used for loading the store):

```
{
  "store": {
    "subdomain": "kounterfitklothing"
  }
}
```

It could be ignoring the setting if you're missing the first set of open/close braces as well, so double check that - and make sure you're using the latest version of Dugway as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I didn't remove the comma after the curly brace.